# using jQuery toggle function on a table row makes table itself grow

Tags: jquery, tablerow

I'm using the jQuery toggle effect hooked to the click() event of 1 table row to toggle the visibility of the next row (which also happens to be the final row in the table).  If I click the firing row multiple times in succession, the table that contains the 2 rows grows a little every time the toggling row shows.

Here's the jQuery I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".sectionhead").click( function() {
        $(this).next("tr").toggle("150");
    });
});
```

So after a few iterations, the table (which has only the tr.sectionhead row visible in it) is quite large.

Is there a built-in way that I can avoid this behaviour, or is there some way of doing this in jQuery that would be easier than what I'm doing?

**Edit**

My actual solution suggested by ScottE's answer below (I don't want to have to class the tr I'm toggling, and it will be visible to start with):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".sectionhead").toggle(
        function() {
            $(this).next("tr").hide();
        },
        function() {
            $(this).next("tr").show();
        }
    )
});
```

Comment: What browser are you using, and can we see some html / css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some weirdness among different browsers with toggling TRs. If you place a border="1" in the table in FF you'll see how the toggling works (or doesn't) as you have it currently coded.

If you go with a toggle(fn, fn) it seems to work in FF and IE7. IE8 could be a different story - so check it as well. [jQuery .toggle() not working with TRs in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975153/jquery-toggle-not-working-with-trs-in-ie) shows a fix if that's the case.

The following assumes that tfoot tr { display: none; } is present in your CSS.

```
$(function() {

    var $tr = $("tfoot tr");

    $(".sectionhead").toggle(
        function() {
            $tr.show();
        },
        function() {
            $tr.hide();
        }
    );

});
```

Comment: Perfect lead to the solution, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to use toggle() as toggle will use the show() method and set the element display to 'block'. In this case, I think you want to have something a little more custom which will set the tr display to 'table-row'.

Comment: Ah, I just saw that ScottE's response worked for you, so clearly I was going in the wrong direction. Glad it got fixed :)