# jQuery UI Autocomplete stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

For some reason jQuery UI's autocomplete has stopped working for me.  I get the same error as is described on [this webpage](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ui-autocomplete-what-am-i-doing-wrong-here).

I've copied the content of the query from that webpage below, hoping that somebody here will be able to answer it.

Thanks!

I am using `Jquery UI Autocomplete` to get a list of names. But for some reason I am getting an error:

[image]

> ```
> $('#repName').removeAttr('readonly').focus(function () {
>                    $(this).val('');
>                }).autocomplete({
>                    source: function (request, response) {
>                        tagId = $('#TagId').val();
>                        $.ajax({
>                            url: '/Developement/GetRepName', type: 'POST', dataType: 'json',
>                            data: { searchText: request.term, maxResults: 10, tagId: tagId },
>                           success: function (data) {
>                               response($.map(data, function (item) {
>                                   return {
>                                       label: item.Name,
>                                       value: item.RepId,
>                                       id: item.RepId
>                                   }
>                               }))
>                           }
>                       })
>                   },
>                   select: function (event, ui) {
>                       commissionAllicationModifications(ui.item.id, 0, 'A');
>                   }
>               });
> ```

I have no clue why this is happening. 
I am using Jquery UI 1.8.1.

I would appreciate any kind of help on this.

It is coming from the jQuery UI 1.8.1 file, specifically jQuery UI Autocomplete 1.8.1.

> ```
>  .menu({
>                focus: function (event, ui) {
>                    var item = ui.item.data("item.autocomplete");
>                    if (false !== self._trigger("focus", null, { item: item })) {
>                        // use value to match what will end up in the input, if it was a key event
>                        if (/^key/.test(event.originalEvent.type)) {
>                            self.element.val(item.value);
>                        }
>                    }
>                },
>                selected: function (event, ui) {
>                    var item = ui.item.data("item.autocomplete");
>                    if (false !== self._trigger("select", event, { item: item })) {
>                        self.element.val(item.value);
>                    }
>                    self.close(event);
>                    // only trigger when focus was lost (click on menu)
>                    var previous = self.previous;
>                    if (self.element[0] !== doc.activeElement) {
>                        self.element.focus();
>                        self.previous = previous;
>                    }
>                    self.selectedItem = item;
>                },
> *                blur: function (event, ui) {
> *                    if (self.menu.element.is(":visible")) {
> *                        self.element.val(self.term);
> *                   }
> *               }
>            })
>            .zIndex(this.element.zIndex() + 1)
>            // workaround for jQuery bug #5781 http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/5781
>            .css({ top: 0, left: 0 })
>            .hide()
>            .data("menu");
> ```

It is weird though because this works flawlessly in another project. What I noticed is when the code hits the [starred] section the self.menu section is undefined. Another thing of note was that it doesn't even send the request. I was thinking that it might be my focus function.

> ```
> .focus(function () {
>      $(this).val('');
> ```

But it is not. 
Thank you for you help.

Comment: You should flag your own respons as the answer. Also, very often this breaks because the returned data has unescaped quotes.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by your second sentence.

I'll be sure to flag my own answer, apparently I can't accept my own answer for two days.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that I included a plugin that defined `$.fn.menu` and this wrought havoc.  I changed it to `$.fn.fg_menu` and the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

What version of jQuery core are you using?

I know of a bug related to [visible detection](http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/1349) and related to [IE8](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-dev/browse_thread/thread/e016fd065149c650?pli=1). If possible, can you upgrade to the most recent jQuery on a test machine and see if that solves your problem?

If you don't feel like upgrading, you could also try hacking jQuery (UGLY!) - [with this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975153/jquery-toggle-not-working-with-trs-in-ie/1104672#1104672):

`if (self.menu.element.is(":visible"))`

becomes

`if (!(self.menu.element.css('display') == 'none'))`

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  I'm using jQuery 1.4.2.  It turns out that this wasn't my problem, but hopefully it will help someone else!