# Why does adding jQuery Mobile cause HTML to vanish?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I've got a simple set of drop down choices modified from this [**SO question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113279/jquery-ui-autocomplete-stopped-working?rq=1).  If I run it in jQuery (w/o JQM), it functions normally, when I add jQuery Mobile, the HTML only flashes on the page then it goes blank and I can't figure out why.  If I enable jQuery Mobile and comment out the last line of the JS:

```
showTab(select.val());
```

It will display all the choices available, instead of the desired result of just a single choice.  In the fiddle below, select jQuery Mobile, and run it, the HTML just disappears after flashing for a sec.

The working fiddle below shows it in the working state I want where only the choice selected by the dropdown is shown after the selection is made.  But I want jQuery Mobile working as well.  Ignore the submit button, it's not hooked up to anything yet.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/delliottg/hYyPQ/)

The HTML:

```
<form>
    <p>
         <h2>Select option to create PCBID:</h2>

        <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
            <option value="pcbids" selected="selected">PCBID Single</option>
            <option value="pcbidr">PCBID Range</option>
            <option value="pcbidq">PCBID Quantity</option>
            <option value="pcbidl">PCBID List</option>
        </select>
    </p>
</form>
<body>
    <div id="pcbids">
        <label>PCBID Single:</label>
        <input type="number" placeholder="12345" title="Just enter a single PCBID number" />
    </div>
    <div id="pcbidl">
        <label>PCBID List:</label>
        <input type="textarea" placeholder="12345,70237,8901" title="Enter a comma separated list of PCBID numbers you're like to create" />
    </div>
    <div id="pcbidr">
        <label>PCBID Range:</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="12345-12400" title="Enter a range separated by a dash (-) and no spaces" />
    </div>
    <div id="pcbidq">
        <label>PCBID Quantity:</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="12345:100" title="Enter a starting PCBID number followed by a colon (:), followed by the sequential number you want to create" />
    </div>
    <label for="submit"></label>
    <input type="button" id="create_button" value="Submit" />
```

The JS:

```
var select = $('#dropdown');
function showTab(name) {
name = '#' + name;
$('div').not(name).hide();
$(name).show();
}

select.change(function () {
showTab($(this).val());
});
//comment out this last line after selecting jQuery Mobile 1.3.1 under Frameworks & Extensions above
showTab(select.val());
```

I've tried loading the code in a `$(document.ready(function(){...}); construct`, as well as  `$(window).load(function() {...});` with the second one I can get the entire list of choices to show up with JQM loaded, but as soon as I choose one, the whole page disappears again.

What am I missing?  If it makes any difference, this is all in Chrome.  For reference, here's [the original fiddle I modified](http://jsfiddle.net/xUAs9/2/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Mobile wraps each `input` and `button` in a div which holds all styles.

When you use `$('div').not(name).hide();`, you hide each and every div in the page, including `input` wrapper. However, when using `.show()`, you show parent div, but all elements are hidden still. Instead, hide div that starts with `pcbid` rather than `div`.

```
$('[id^=pcbid]').not(name).hide();
$(name).show();
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/hYyPQ/3/)**

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks for the quick answer and the education.  I didn't realize that JQM wraps input & button in divs.  Thanks for the example as well.