# jquery toggle not working in chrome but working in IE and firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

Hi Guys
I have a page where i m displaying text in a span and that span control toggles on click of a button, basically i m using jquery for this. Its working fine on IE and firefox but on chrome when i click on the close button(which is there in the span to toggle it) it does not work for the first time i click on it but works after first click.

please advice, code is below

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Assets/JS/jquery.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
        $.showmsg = function (msgEle, msgText, autoHide, isSuccess) {
            var tblMsg;
            var imgType;
            if (isSuccess) {
                imgType = "<img src='Assets/Images/icon_status_success_26x26.gif'/>"
            } else {
                imgType = "<img src='Assets/Images/icon_status_fail_26x26.gif'/>"
            }

            tblMsg = '<div id="container" style="width: 400px;"><b class="rtop"><b class="r1"></b><b class="r2"></b><b class="r3"></b><b class="r4"></b></b><div class="contain"><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class=""><tr><td style="width:30px;" align="center" valign="middle">' + imgType + '</td><td>' + msgText + '</td><td style="width:30px;" align="center" valign="middle"><a href="javascript:void(0);"  onclick="$(\'#' + msgEle + '\').toggle(50);"><img src="Assets/Images/hide-icon.gif" border="0" alt="Hide" title="Hide"/></a></td></tr></table></div><b class="rbottom"><b class="r4"></b><b class="r3"></b><b class="r2"></b><b class="r1"></b></b></div>';
            $("#" + msgEle).html(tblMsg);
            $("#" + msgEle).show();
            if (autoHide) {
                setTimeout(function () { $('#' + msgEle).fadeOut('normal') }, 10000);
            }
        }


        function Delete1() {
            $.showmsg('spnMessage', "Deleted", false, true);
        }

    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .rtop, .rbottom
        {
            display: block;
        }
        .rtop *, .rbottom *
        {
            display: block;
            height: 1px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .r1
        {
            margin: 0 5px;
            background: yellow;
        }
        .r2
        {
            margin: 0 3px;
            background: yellow;
        }
        .r3
        {
            margin: 0 2px;
            background: yellow;
        }
        .r4
        {
            margin: 0 1px;
            height: 2px;
            background: yellow;
        }
        .contain
        {
            background: yellow;
            text-align: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete"  OnClientClick="Delete1(); return false;" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="spnMessage" style="display: none;"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this thread [jQuery .toggle() not working with TRs in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975153/jquery-toggle-not-working-with-trs-in-ie)

Answer (score 2):

I had this very annoying problem as well.  I assume it has something to do with a quirk in our HTML because other places on the same page work just fine.

The only way I was able to solve this problem was to do:

```
if($(#'element_id').css('display') == 'none'){
   $(#'element_id').show();
}else{
   $(#'element_id').hide();
}
```